# Having problems with my post system

Tags: php, mysql

I know the basics of MySQL and PHP. I've set up a posting system that echoes the fields from my table.

The only problem is, since this is a news page, the newest posts need to be on top. And when the page echoes back the results, it puts the first entry I made (in the table) at the top.

This is my code:

```
// Selecting The Table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts")
or die(mysql_error());
// Connecting To The Rows, And Echoing Back The Results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='post'>";
    echo "Title: " . $row['title']; 
    echo "<br />";
    echo $row['content'];
    echo "</div>";
```

I am not sure how to make the latest post the first to show up.
I still want it to echo back the older entries though.

I can use phpMyAdmin if necessary.

Comment: You should have a datetime column in your table, and timestamp every entry as it's posted. Then you can use an `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order your results.

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date_posted DESC
```